# code run on ginger bread but not working on Jelly Bean?

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am doing DOM xml parsing,My code is working perfectly on Ginger bread while not working on Jelly Bean. showing `NullPointerException` . on below line got error.

```
 NodeList n1= doc.getElementsByTagName("dua_detail");
```

I took xml File from assets folder perfectly on AsyncTask.

```
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.example.zad_e_rah.Finalview.pinpointxml(Finalview.java:67)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.example.zad_e_rah.Finalview$GetAudiojokefromserver.onPostExecute(Finalview.java:333)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.example.zad_e_rah.Finalview$GetAudiojokefromserver.onPostExecute(Finalview.java:1)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 18:01:23.785: E/AndroidRuntime(3575):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

Comment: Can you post your code snippet ??

Comment: Please specify some source of Finalview.java. Especially code related to `onPostExecute` will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the above line is really the line that throws the exception, the doc-object is probably null. You should check that.

Since you didn't provide more code I cannot tell you why it is null.